# C++ Windows Form Application: Attempted to read or write protected memory (unmanaged class)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, boost, c++-cli

I'm trying to use Boost library in my C++ Windows Form Application and I always get an exception:

> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and Boost version 1.57.0. Previously I used Boost version 1.56.0 but upgrading didn't solve my issue.

Here are the code:

**MyForm.cpp**

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
void main(cli::array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    TestUnmanaged::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

**MyForm.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "ExternalProfileManager.h"

#define DEFAULT_PROFILE_NAME    "profile.bin"

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "lib/edk.lib")

namespace TestUnmanaged {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    ExternalProfileManager profileManager;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
            profileManager.load(DEFAULT_PROFILE_NAME);

            std::vector<std::string> profileList;
            profileManager.listProfile(profileList);

        }
```

**ExternalProfileManager.h**

```
#ifndef EXTERNAL_PROFILE_MANAGER_H
#define EXTERNAL_PROFILE_MANAGER_H

#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/tracking.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>

class ExternalProfileManager
{
    ExternalProfileManager(const ExternalProfileManager&) {};
    ExternalProfileManager& operator = (const ExternalProfileManager&) {};

protected:
    std::map<std::string, std::string > _profiles;
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::string >::iterator profileItr_t;

    // Boost serialization support
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int /*file version */)
    {
        ar & _profiles;
    }

public:
    ExternalProfileManager();
    virtual ~ExternalProfileManager();

    virtual bool        save(const std::string& location);
    virtual bool        load(const std::string& location);
    virtual bool        insertProfile(const std::string& name, const unsigned char* profileBuf, unsigned int bufSize);
    virtual bool        listProfile(std::vector<std::string>& profiles);
};

//BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(ExternalProfileManager);
//BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(ExternalProfileManager, boost::serialization::track_never);

#endif // EXTERNAL_PROFILE_MANAGER_H
```

**ExternalProfileManager.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 4267)  // "conversion from size_t to unsigned int"
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#include <boost/archive/archive_exception.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#pragma warning(pop)

#include "ExternalProfileManager.h"

using namespace std;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

ExternalProfileManager::ExternalProfileManager()
{
}

ExternalProfileManager::~ExternalProfileManager()
{
}

bool ExternalProfileManager::save(const string& location)
{
    ofstream ofs(location.c_str(), ios_base::binary);
    if ( !ofs.is_open() ) return false;
    try {
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << *this;
    }
    catch (boost::archive::archive_exception& )
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool ExternalProfileManager::load(const string& location)
{
    ifstream ifs(location.c_str(), ios_base::binary);
    if ( !ifs.is_open() ) return false;
    try { 
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> *this;
    }
    catch (boost::archive::archive_exception& )
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool ExternalProfileManager::insertProfile(const string& name, const unsigned char* profileBuf, unsigned int bufSize)
{
    assert(profileBuf);
    // Replace our stored bytes with the contents of the buffer passed by the caller
    string bytesIn(profileBuf, profileBuf+bufSize);
    _profiles[name] = bytesIn;
    return true;
}
bool ExternalProfileManager::listProfile(vector<string>& profiles)
{
    profiles.clear();
    for ( profileItr_t itr = _profiles.begin(); itr != _profiles.end(); ++itr ) {
        profiles.push_back(itr->first);
    }
    return true;
}
```

The error occurred in `ia >> *this;` in `ExternalProfileManager::load` (thrown in file `basic_archive.cpp`). So calling `profileManager.load(DEFAULT_PROFILE_NAME);` from form constructor will trigger the exception.
Calling `save` will also trigger the same exception but **other functions which have no** `this` **will work fine**.

I tried creating a **console application in VS 2012** and call ExternalProfileManager.h **and it works perfectly** (including save, load, and any other function). Here are the simple console application I created to test it:

**Console.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "ExternalProfileManager.h"

#define DEFAULT_PROFILE_NAME    "profile.bin"

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "lib/edk.lib")

ExternalProfileManager profileManager;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    profileManager.load(DEFAULT_PROFILE_NAME);

    std::vector<std::string> profileList;
    profileManager.listProfile(profileList);

    std::cout << "Available profiles:" << std::endl;

    for (size_t i=0; i < profileList.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << i+1 << ". " << profileList.at(i);
        if (i+1 < profileList.size()) {
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

*profile.bin* is generated from calling save function in console application and contain serialized data generated by boost. I can provide the file if it is needed to solve this issue.

I have also tried to create a simple class wrapper but the exception still occurred.
**WrapperExternalProfileManager.h**

```
#ifndef WRAPPER_EXTERNAL_PROFILE_MANAGER_H
#define WRAPPER_EXTERNAL_PROFILE_MANAGER_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class WrapperExternalProfileManager
{
    WrapperExternalProfileManager(const WrapperExternalProfileManager&) {};
    WrapperExternalProfileManager& operator = (const WrapperExternalProfileManager&) {};

public:
    WrapperExternalProfileManager();
    virtual ~WrapperExternalProfileManager();
    virtual bool        save(const std::string& location);
    virtual bool        load(const std::string& location);
    virtual bool        insertProfile(const std::string& name, const unsigned char* profileBuf, unsigned int bufSize);
    virtual bool        listProfile(std::vector<std::string>& profiles);
};

#endif
```

**WrapperExternalProfileManager.cpp**

```
#include "WrapperExternalProfileManager.h"
#include "ExternalProfileManager.h"

using namespace std;

ExternalProfileManager profileManager;

WrapperExternalProfileManager::WrapperExternalProfileManager()
{
    std::cout<<"Constructor WrapperExternalProfileManager"<<std::endl;
}

WrapperExternalProfileManager::~WrapperExternalProfileManager()
{

}

bool WrapperExternalProfileManager::save(const string& location)
{
    return profileManager.save(location);
}

bool WrapperExternalProfileManager::load(const string& location)
{
    return profileManager.load(location);
}

bool WrapperExternalProfileManager::insertProfile(const string& name, const unsigned char* profileBuf, unsigned int bufSize)
{
    return profileManager.insertProfile(name, profileBuf, bufSize);
}

bool WrapperExternalProfileManager::listProfile(vector<string>& profiles)
{
    return profileManager.listProfile(profiles);
}
```

`save` and `load` still trigger the exception but other functions work perfectly.

Here are some property of the application which might be helpful:

- Linker -> System -> SubSystem: **Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)**
- General -> Common Language Runtime Support: **Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)**

I know I have done something incorrectly but I don't know which part. Any suggestion to solve this issue would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "other functions which have no this will work fine" - what does that mean?

Comment: "I tried creating a console application in VS 2012 and call ExternalProfileManager.h and it works perfectly" - usually indicates that you have [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). E.g. you call the serialization functions _after_ the objects were destructed (but there are many forms of undefined behaviour, including but not limited to memory corruption (out of bounds reads / writes), uninitialized memory, data races, some integer overflow situations etc.

Comment: @sehe: Thanks for your comment. "other functions which have no this will work fine" -> ExternalProfileManager has several functions (save, load, insertProfile, and listProfile). Save and load (which has a pointer this) throw the exception but the other two run just fine. About the destructed object, I'm not sure how I can check that case.

Comment: FTR that's called _non-static (or instance) method functions_. And it's a pretty darn good clue which pointer is dangling :)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to find the source of your Undefined Behaviour (use static analysis tools, heap checking and divide and conquer).

I've just built your code on VS2013 RTM, using a ultra-simple C# console application as the driver:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var f = new TestUnmanaged.MyForm();
            f.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

This JustWorks(TM).

I created a `profile.bin` with 100 random profiles of varying length:

```
#if 1
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        std::vector<uint8_t> buf;
        std::generate_n(back_inserter(buf), rand() % 1024, rand);
        insertProfile("profile" + std::to_string(i), buf.data(), buf.size());
    }
    save(location);
#endif
```

And they are deserialized just fine.

Good luck.

#### Download the full project here http://downloads.sehe.nl/stackoverflow/q27032092.zip in case you want to fiddle with it (compare the details?)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to check it out and inform you.

Comment: Hi Suse. Just a quick follow up. I've tried your project and, as you said, it seems to load and save correctly! I will try to implement this to my actual application tomorrow and will inform you. But, just to confirm, you're building C# console application merely to call the C++ form. I need to confirm this because my actual application will have several forms with several .cpp files and .h files, and I haven't used this method before.

Comment: That was a random choice (I had a ConsoleApplication1 project already there). You can use a usual GUI project type instead. I just tried the quickest way to reproduce the crash :/

Comment: Hello Sehe. I've done comparing your project and mine. At first, I thought that using C# console application to open the C++ form will solve the issue and preventing the same exception to be thrown. But I realize it's totally wrong. I then realize that commenting `#pragma comment(lib, "lib/edk.lib")` will stop the exception. But, my application need the dependencies or else _unresolved token_ error will occur. I'm sorry that I can't provide you the file. I'll try to contact the authorities to check about this issue. Thanks Sehe for your help :)

Comment: You should check that edk.lib itself (without /using/ any of the library symbols) causes the issue. If so, recompile all libraries using ABI compatible (i.e. identical) compiler settings. There's UB if there are ABI differences between the objects participating in the link

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're suggesting to include edk.lib in the project without calling any function (which needs the library) from project. If so, I have tried it. The simple example I provided doesn't need the library symbol (thus you can copy it, comment out the `#pragma comment(lib, "lib/edk.lib")`, it runs perfectly). I'm sorry, but can you elaborate more about _ABI compatible_ and _UB_? I'm not sure I can recompile the library since I don't own the code.

Comment: Assuming that this is referring to the infamous **[Exchange development kit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonjoh/archive/2004/08/01/using-the-edk-libraries-effectively.aspx)** _[sic]_ you may be in a bit of a bind. I'd suggest either retrieving a copy of VS6.0 and using that, or try to find a supported SDK.

Comment: No. Edk.lib is coming from [Emotiv](emotiv.com). I'm still waiting for their response. I hope they can solve this issue. Do you think by creating ExternalProfileManager as an external .dll and then calling this .dll from my core application will resolve this issue?

Comment: I just want to inform you that I've already solved the issue. I create .dll for ExternalProfileManager and have my main application to refer to it. Now the application can load and save profile successfully and not throwing error. Thanks Sehe for your help.

Comment: Oh, I guess this is also what I did? Or you mean, you moved the Boost Serialization stuff into a native-only dll and call /that/ from a mixed-mode assembly? To be honest, if that solves it, I'd be very wary of undefined behaviour. Likely you're just not seeing the results of mixing e.g. runtime versions. Or, perhaps, you made the build settings match those of the edk library better, without noticing (you could review the differences, and if there are differences, it should logically work just as well in the mixed-mode assembly).

Comment: Yes, I moved the Boost Serialization stuff (including the whole definition of the class) into a native-only dll (I create a new C++ empty project and had set the output to dll). Now I'm not sure about build settings but I think the case is like what you've mentioned, that the build setting accidentally match with those library. I'm afraid the difference is between the Character Set or Common Language Runtime Support.